# How to play videoClip by Quicktime player in Livecode?

Tags: livecode

I import video files as control and I create a QT player on my card.
In the script this card. I set the filename of player to name of the video file.

```
on opencard
  set the filename of player "Player" to "vdo.mov"
end opencard
```

At runtime this script has worked. But when I save standalone application. It's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to the video file in the standalone application settings:

1. Open the standalone application page from the file menu
2. Go to the copy files tab
3. Add your video file or a folder containing your video file
4. Build your standalone

The standalone will be build with the video file in your application bundle.

Comment: Thank you for answer. If I don't build standalone application. I want to save to livecode file for sending to my colleague. The player hasn't played.

Comment: I would create a folder with the LiveCode file and video file together. Zip it and send it to him.